# C# project reference and hintpath using variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

We have a VS2017 C# solution which contains multiple projects. Each project contains several references and some contain a hintpath. This path is currently a hardcoded string.

Does VS2017 provide the ability to define a variable/macro at solution level that will be resolved if used as part of hintpath.

For example, currently the hintpath might say 
*"c:\thirdparty\comp\1.2.3\my_assembly.dll"*

and we would like something like this;
*"${thirdparty}\comp\1.2.3\my_assembly.dll"*

Appreciate any input.